# Reference files globally in VS Code (JS)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a website that I am using Grunt to concat files.  I am wondering if there is currently some way to reference my Bower packages in all of my JS files as I use those packages within my files.

Example: I include 'moment' as a Bower package and then when I reference 
'moment' in my JS file within VS Code I get a warning that 'moment' does not exist.  This is annoying because I know it exists globally and would like to be able to manually reference it for code completion (and to get rid of the warning).

Comment: I am trying to figure out the same thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can omit the warning by adding the following to the top of your sources:

```
/*global moment*/
```

You can also create a `globals.js` file, add all those global definitions to it and reference it from your sources like this:

```
/// <reference path="global.js" />
```

Comment: Should the `/// <reference path="..." />` allow code completion?  It doesn't seem to really do anything (including dismiss warnings) even though it is highlighted differently (it's something special).  The `/*global moment*/` does remove the warnings, which is a little satisfying though. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, I only upvoted this for now and if I can figure out how to properly reference my files then I will accept this as the right answer.  I tried the putting the `reference path` in a `globals.js` file as well as where I'm using `moment` (eg: `/// <reference path="../../../bower_components/moment/moment.js" />` at the top of my js and `/// <reference path="bower_components/moment/moment.js" />` in globals.js in the root of my project)

Comment: Did you figure out a way to get this to work? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the /// <reference path= routine is only applicable when using all TypeScript files, not plain Javascript files for libraries.